# RabbitMQ - StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Received ERROR {message=[Bad CONNECT]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am using reactor-spring-core , 2.0.7.RELEASE . 
Trying to connect to RabbitMQ and getting :

StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Received ERROR {message=[Bad CONNECT]

Got any idea why ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I'm sure you have to see something else in application logs. Otherwise try to switch on `DEBUG` logging level for the `org.springframework` category and look for something "interesting" in logs after trying to connect.

Comment: Thanks Artem , good Idea , But still no solution there

Comment: Yeah... I understand that solution might not be there. But I just wonder if there som StackTace about `Bad CONNECT` in the logs.

Comment: that's what I am getting .                                                                  "NettyTcpClient - Failed to connect to /10.2.1.188:61613. Attempting reconnect in 5000ms"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it ! :-)

Should put in rabbitmq.config the following :

[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].

and it will work with guest/guest credentials :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using spring boot stomp with rabbitmq, This configuration solved the issue -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketChatConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final String rabbitHost;
    private final int rabbitStompPort;
    private final String rabbitUser;
    private final String rabbitPass;

    public WebSocketChatConfig(@Value("${RABBITMQ_HOST}") String rabbitHost,
                               @Value("${RABBITMQ_STOMP_PORT}") String rabbitStompPort,
                               @Value("${RABBITMQ_USER}") String rabbitUser,
                               @Value("${RABBITMQ_PASS}") String rabbitPass) {
        this.rabbitHost = rabbitHost;
        this.rabbitStompPort = Integer.parseInt(rabbitStompPort);
        this.rabbitUser = rabbitUser;
        this.rabbitPass = rabbitPass;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocketApp").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
                .setRelayHost(rabbitHost)
                .setRelayPort(rabbitStompPort)
                .setClientLogin(rabbitUser)
                .setClientPasscode(rabbitPass)
                .setSystemLogin(rabbitUser)
                .setSystemPasscode(rabbitPass);
    }
}
```

Note : setSystemLogin and setSystemPasscode is required(This is not mentioned in the documentation and took me 2 hours to figure out) because rabbitMq uses SystemLogin(default :"guest") and systemPasscode (default:guest) to connect in heartbeat